# How to set the height of the DrawerHeader exactly to the height of the AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following code you can see that the heights of the Drawer Header and the Appbar are slightly the same. For that I used the height property in the drawer header:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
AppBar appBar = AppBar(
    title: Text("Home Screen", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey);
return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 112,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              child: Text(
                "Menu",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey),
            ),
          ),
```

But on the first Screen Shot you can see the result on an iPhone 12 Pro Max simulator and on the second Screen Shot you can see the result on an iPhone 11 simulator. It is recognizable that the heights do not exactly match:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKdJH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIukU.png)

How can I set both heights to the same size, in order to avoid working with the height property?

Answer (score 2):

The appbar default height is a constant (56.0), you can use kToolbarHeight from *flutter/src/material/constants.dart* package to get it.

Comment: I already tried to use kToolbarHeight ... but the size is still different or sometime it's matching but it depends on which device.

Comment: I recommand you to open an issue on the flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues